# Issue with Flat File Document Parser

Tags: knime

I have a text file which size is 6.8 MB. After loading it to [Flat File Document Parser](https://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_labs_textprocessing_io_Flat_File_Document_Parser.html) and executing its start processing till 99% and after that it stuckes there for hours without any error. Any suggetions please.

Best wishes

Alam

Comment: I also ran into this topic on the KNIME forum. If anyone wants to follow: https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-textprocessing/flat-file-document-parser-problem

Answer (score 1):

Between 99% and 100% the "Flat File Document Parser" node tries to build the Document data cell. 
With a file of 500Kb, i had to wait ~10sec to finish the job. 
I think that your file is too big to be loaded in the "Flat File Document Parser" node. 
You can try to increase the memory allocated to KNIME in your knime.ini file but i don't know if this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already increased it to 2048. But still not working. Can i increase it more?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just may need to wait. If you turn on the Heap Monitor (File->Preferences->Show heap status) you'll see the KNIME is diligently processing the file. I just tried reading a 4.8MB file in, and it took quite a while to process, i.e., over an hour and this is a blazing fast machine.